# hide image title in slide show

Tags: views

Trying to show **just** the images in a slideshow '***view***'.
Not sure where to turn the title off, I've tried changing it to ***`<none>`***,
but it's still printing out over the image. I even changed it under '***manage display***' to hidden field and I'm unchecking the default option of creating a label.
Where do I need to adjust this at?

[image: capture3]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the FORMAT to **Show: Fields** and then **add** only your image field and configure its formatter to show what you need – original image or image style or URL to image ...

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I've been looking at that for over an hour